# Finding Duplicate Entries in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with the following fields in Oracle 10g.

TABLE_1

account_no | tracking_id | trans_amount

Each account_no can have multiple tracking Id's and transaction amounts.

How do i query out the duplicate entries of account_no where tracking lies between 1 and 1000, and the corresponding trans_amount ?

Many thanks in advance for your help,

novice.

Comment: Can you clarify your expectations with sample input and output?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have found the solution. But I will post some sample data next time i'm asking around :)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT account_no, tracking_id, trans_amount
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE
account_no IN
    (
    SELECT account_no FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE tracking_id >= 1 AND tracking_id <= 1000
    GROUP BY account_do
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Explanation of the subquery: it finds all the `account_no`'s for which there are more than 1 such that its `tracking_id` is between 1 and 1000.

I hope that's what you meant.