# Find duplicate entries in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `messcuts` table with the following structure.
`id`, `student_rollno`, `date`.

The problem is there are some records duplicated ie. two records with same `student_rollno` in the same `date`. How do I remove them? Eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `messcuts` 
WHERE student_rollno =  'b070226'

|id |student_rollno|date
|259|B070226|2011-08-06
|260|B070226|2011-08-07
|1485|B070226|2011-08-12
|1486|B070226|2011-08-13
|1487|B070226|2011-08-14
|1488|B070226|2011-08-15
|2372|B070226|2011-08-27
|2369|B070226|2011-08-24
|2368|B070226|2011-08-23
|2371|B070226|2011-08-26
|2374|B070226|2011-08-29
|2373|B070226|2011-08-28
|2370|B070226|2011-08-25
|2367|B070226|2011-08-22
|2375|B070226|2011-08-30
|2376|B070226|2011-08-31
|2938|b070226|2011-08-06
```

See on 2011-08-06 there are two records.

Comment: i've editted the questions. please see.

Comment: Do you want to delete the duplicates or make a distinct select?

Comment: How do you decide which ones to delete?

Comment: i want to delete the duplicates.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900065/how-to-delete-duplicate-values-in-mysql-table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Duplicate Entries in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275930/finding-duplicate-entries-in-a-table)

Comment: The SO search for '[sql] duplicate entries' finds 4,000 odd questions.

Comment: @Shahal, check my answer! that will solve your problem :)

Comment: @Skeet. I've already entered a lot of data. i've moved my code to follow ur way in fact, but i need to remove the old records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select student_rollno, date 
from messcuts 
group by student_rollno, date 
having count(*) > 1
```

and to delete:

```
delete from messcuts d where d.id in (
    select max(s.id) 
    from messcuts as s 
    group by s.student_rollno, s.date 
    having count(*) > 1)
```

if not working in mysql:

```
delete from messcuts 
using messcuts, messcuts as v_messcuts
where messcuts.id <> v_messcuts.id
and messcuts.student_rollno = v_messcuts.student_rollno
and messcuts.date = v_messcuts.date
```

Comment: i want to delete the duplicates

Comment: @Shahal, smart thing to do is prevent your php script to insert redundant data :) so just follow my answer. Once you don't have duplicates than you don't have to worry about deleting them ever :)

Comment: @roselan: it's showing the following error: You can't specify target table 'messcuts' for update in FROM clause.

Answer (score -1):

This will show the duplicates

```
SELECT * 
FROM messcuts
WHERE (student_rollno,date) IN
    (
    SELECT student_rollno,date
    FROM messcuts
    GROUP BY student_rollno,date
    HAVING count(*)>1
    )
```

and to delete:

```
CREATE VIEW dups AS
SELECT MAX(id) as id
    FROM messcuts
    GROUP BY student_rollno,date
    HAVING count(*)>1
```

you will need to run this several times to get rid of all duplicates

```
DELETE FROM t2 
WHERE id IN (SELECT  id FROM dups)
```

once you have removed the duplicates It may be a good idea to add a unique constraint to stop furthur problems.

```
ALTER TABLE messcuts ADD UNIQUE std_dte (student_rollno,date)
```

Comment: +1, Do I need explanation ;) ? some people just don't read before they downvote